# Replacement of deprecated enqueueMessage() from JApplication

Tags: joomla-api, joomla-3.7

I have noticied that method enqueueMessage() from JApplication has been marked as deprecated, but what is the replacement method for that ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire `JApplication` class has been marked deprecated. Instead, you need to use `JApplicationCms`.

So to display an alert, you can use the following:

```
$app = JApplicationCms::getInstance('site');
$app->enqueueMessage('My Message here', 'success');
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not deprecated on JApplicationCms, the best way to call it would be:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication()
$app->enqueueMessage('My Message here', 'success');
```

See https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JFactory.html#method_getApplication for more details and to see that it returns JApplicationCms